# How to install java/mysql connector in XAMPP?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I need to use MySql as a database for my project along with jsp.

If I have MySql server separately i could install in it. But I have XAMPP. If I try to install it in MySql directory of XAMPP somehow, does it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I try to install it in MySql directory of XAMPP somehow, does it
>   works??

Because XAMPP already install MySql and use the default port `3306` so if you want to install a new MySql you need :

1. Remove XAMPP, and install MySql or,
2. Install MySql with another port number **(this is the best way)**

**EDIT**

You should to include your MySql JDBC Connector in your project `class path`, because XAMPP It isn't supposed to keep any kind of library.

Comment: What I am asking is installing mysql/java connector in XAMPP's Mysql works ??

Comment: @SKJ this is not possible you should to include your `mysql/java connect` in your project class path, because XAMPP It isn't supposed to keep any kind of library.